# module name from method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have simple code

```
module Foo
  def foo
    p self
    #p 'Foo' -> bad decision for me
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

Bar.new.foo #=> #<Bar:0x00000002f0faf8>
```

But I need something like this

```
Bar.new.foo #=> Foo
```

I need the name of the module from which this method was called.
So, what are the ways to find out the name of the module

Comment: where is metaprogramming?

Comment: @Monk_Code That definition is a bit controversial :-)

Comment: @Monk_Code It's just for some metaprogramming decisions, if it's possible, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do as below :

```
module Foo
  def foo
    method(__method__).owner
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

Bar.new.foo # => Foo
```